Updating callback parameters for sending post requests to a site
It is simple enough to send a GET request to the url https://apps.fpb.org.za/erms/fpbquerytitle.aspx?filmtitle=&Submit1=Search to get the 1st page of search results of the wesbite.
However, I cannot figure out how to request subsequent pages, which involve sending a POST request to the same url but with a lot form data parameters.
I have managed to get the results of page 2 as follows
with requests.session() as s:

    ### REQUESTING FIRST PAGE

    r = s.request('get', 'https://apps.fpb.org.za/erms/fpbquerytitle.aspx?filmtitle=&Submit1=Search')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')


    ### REQUESTING SECOND PAGE

    page_number = 2
    form_data = {
        '__EVENTTARGET': '',
        '__EVENTARGUMENT': '',   
        '__VIEWSTATE': soup.find('input', id = '__VIEWSTATE').get('value'),
        '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR': soup.find('input', id = '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR').get('value'),
        '__EVENTVALIDATION': soup.find('input', id = '__EVENTVALIDATION').get('value'),
        'vwfpbquerytitle_DXKVInput': soup.find('input', id = 'vwfpbquerytitle_DXKVInput').get('value'),
        'vwfpbquerytitle$CallbackState': soup.find('input', id = 'vwfpbquerytitle_CallbackState').get('value'),
        'vwfpbquerytitle$DXSelInput': soup.find('input', id = 'vwfpbquerytitle_DXSelInput').get('value'),
        'vwfpbquerytitle_DXHFPWS': soup.find('input', id = 'vwfpbquerytitle_DXHFPWS').get('value'),
        'popupControlWS': soup.find('input', id = 'popupControlWS').get('value'),     
        'DXScript': '1_155,1_87,1_147,1_97,1_123,1_106,1_113,1_84,1_139,1_137,1_98,1_135',
        '__CALLBACKID': 'vwfpbquerytitle',
        '__CALLBACKPARAM': (
            f"c0:KV|777;{soup.find('input', id = 'vwfpbquerytitle_DXKVInput').get('value')};GB|20;12|PAGERONCLICK3|PN{page_number - 1};",
        ),
    }
    r2 = s.request('post', 'https://apps.fpb.org.za/erms/fpbquerytitle.aspx?filmtitle=&Submit1=Search', data = form_data)
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

But the last response r2 does not give me any indication for what the constantly changing __CALLBACKPARAM and vwfpbquerytitle$CallbackState parameters should be for the next request, as they are not present anywhere in the HTML response. In fact the only reason I can set the __CALLBACKPARAM correctly for the 2nd request above is because I can see by inspecting the website that the patterns such as c0:KV|777, etc. are always there for that 2nd request.
So my question is how can I request subsequent pages past this point? Because setting __CALLBACKPARAM in the previous way, e.g.
page_number = 5
'__CALLBACKPARAM': f"c0:KV|777;{soup.find('input', id = 'vwfpbquerytitle_DXKVInput').get('value')};GB|20;12|PAGERONCLICK3|PN{page_number - 1};"

just gives me the same 2nd page of results as before

first you could use print() to see what you have in form_data before you send POST. Next you could send request to url https://httpbin.org/post  and it will send you all data which you send - and you can compare it with request which makes browser for original page - you can check it in DevTool (tab: Network) in Chrome/Firefox

did you check what you get in r.content? Maybe you can't find new values because it send you Captcha or warning instead of table.

did you check if web page works without JavaScript? I turned off JavaScript and I can't click next pages. It seems it uses JavaScript to send requests - and probably it uses JavaScript to get new data (maybe even as JSON) and replace data in HTML. But requests and Beautifulsoup can't run JavaScript - so you may need to use Selenium to control real web browser which can run JavaScript. OR you have to check if JavaScript get it as JSON (or check what you get in r.content) and get data directly from JSON.

The only variable part of __CALLBACKPARAM that matters is:
PAGERONCLICK{}, 2{};12 and PN{}.
__VIEWSTATE, __CALLBACKID and vwfpbquerytitle$CallbackState don't actually need to be changed.
credit to @xoxouser for figuring out that 777 was the length of str(array), it was the only part that seemed random, but in the end it did not actually matter; as long as it is consistent with the supplied array.
Here's the code:
import requests

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/126.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
}

params = {
    'filmtitle': '',
    'Submit1': 'Search',
}

data = {
    "__VIEWSTATE": "/wEPDwUKLTMyMDI3MDk3MQ9kFgICAw9kFgICAQ88KwAaAgAPFgIeD0RhdGFTb3VyY2VCb3VuZGdkFzwrAAYBBRQrAAJkZGQYAgUeX19Db250cm9sc1JlcXVpcmVQb3N0QmFja0tleV9fFgUFD3Z3ZnBicXVlcnl0aXRsZQUVdndmcGJxdWVyeXRpdGxlJERYSEZQBSJ2d2ZwYnF1ZXJ5dGl0bGUkRFhIRlAkVFBDRkNtMSRUQyRPBSJ2d2ZwYnF1ZXJ5dGl0bGUkRFhIRlAkVFBDRkNtMSRUQyRDBQxwb3B1cENvbnRyb2wFEUVudGl0eURhdGFTb3VyY2UxDzwrAAkBAQ9oZGQs+akQiwv01gWVLky5TJXi94fPtkrfInkrLr1p5PmBGQ==",
    "__CALLBACKID": "vwfpbquerytitle",
    "vwfpbquerytitle$CallbackState": "BwMHAgIERGF0YQb+GgAAAACfmwAAn5sAAAAAAABkAAAAAAYAAAAKbWF0ZXJpYWxpZAptYXRlcmlhbGlkBAAADW1hdGVyaWFsdGl0bGUNbWF0ZXJpYWx0aXRsZQcAABBwdWJsaWNhdGlvbl95ZWFyEHB1YmxpY2F0aW9uX3llYXIDAAALcnVudGltZV9taW4LcnVudGltZV9taW4HAAAUbWF0Zm9ybWF0ZGVzY3JpcHRpb24UbWF0Zm9ybWF0ZGVzY3JpcHRpb24HAAACY2ECY2EHAAAAAAAABwAHAAcABwAG//8EBV1DAQAHAg8gQSBET0dTIEpPVVJORVkDBuMHBwIDMTA4BwISRElHSVRBTCBWSURFTyBESVNDBwIKNy05UEcgRCAgVgcABwAG//8EBVAuAQAHAhEgQkFMTEVSUyBTRUFTT04gMQMG4AcHAgMyNzEHAhJESUdJVEFMIFZJREVPIERJU0MHAgoxNiBEICBMICBTBwAHAAb//wQFlCABAAcCDSBCT0JCWSBKQVNPT1MDBt4HBwIDMTIwBwIIVEhFQVRSRSAHAgRQRyBWBwAHAAb//wQGFmsHAgwgQ0xPVUQgQVRMQVMDBt0HBwIDMTY1BwISRElHSVRBTCBWSURFTyBESVNDBwIIMTYgTCBTIFYHAAcABv//BAUSUAEABwIoIERFTU9OIFNMQVlFUiAtVE8gVEhFIFNXT1JEU01JVEggVklMTEFHRQMG5wcHAgMxMTAHAgdUSEVBVFJFBwIEMTMgVgcABwAG//8EBcRSAQAHAgogSU1BR0lOQVJZAwboBwcCAzEwNAcCB1RIRUFUUkUHAg0xNiBEICBIICBMICBWBwAHAAb//wQFXEoBAAcCHiBNQVlBIFRIRSBCRUUgMztUSEUgR09MREVOIE9SQgMG5QcHAgI4OAcCB1RIRUFUUkUHAgNQRyAHAAcABv//BAWtIgEABwIWIE1JS0UgJiBNT0xMWSBTRUFTT04gNAMG3gcHAgM0MTMHAhJESUdJVEFMIFZJREVPIERJU0MHAgcxMyBEICBMBwAHAAb//wQFpVIBAAcCFSBNT1RIRVLigJlTIElOU1RJTkNUIAMG6AcHAgI5NAcCB1RIRUFUUkUHAg4xNiBDVCAgRCAgUyAgVgcABwAG//8EBdgjAQAHAhAgUk9CT1QgT1ZFUkxPUkRTAwbeBwcCAjkwBwIIVEhFQVRSRSAHAgkxMC0xMlBHIFYHAAcABv//BAW1UAEABwIlIFNQSURFUi1NQU4gOiBBQ1JPU1MgVEhFIFNQSURFUi1WRVJTRQMG5wcHAgMxNDAHAgdUSEVBVFJFBwIHMTMgTCAgVgcABwAG//8EBTxTAQAHAhYgVEhFIEJPWSBBTkQgVEhFIEhFUk9OAwboBwcCAzEyNQcCB1RIRUFUUkUHAgc3LTlQRyBWBwAHAAb//wQFliMBAAcCHCBUSEUgQ1VSU0UgT0YgSElHSFdBWSBTSEVJTEEDBt4HBwIDMTMwBwIIVEhFQVRSRSAHAg4xMyBIICBMICBTViAgVgcABwAG//8EBTxQAQAHAicgVEhFIFVOTElLRUxZIFBJTEdSSU1BR0UgT0YgSEFST0xEIEZSWSADBucHBwIDMTA4BwIHVEhFQVRSRQcCCjE2IEQgIEwgIFYHAAcABv//BAWZMwEABwIQIFRIRSBXSE9MRSBUUlVUSAMG3wcHAgEyBwIIVEhFQVRSRSAHAgMxMCAHAAcABv//BAYdAgcCAyIxIgMG3QcHAgMxMDcHAhJESUdJVEFMIFZJREVPIERJU0MHAgZQRyBMIFYHAAcABv//BAYzYQcCEyMxIENIRUVSTEVBREVSIENBTVADBtsHBwICOTIHAhJESUdJVEFMIFZJREVPIERJU0MHAggxNiBMIE4gUwcABwAG//8EBURSAQAHAhcjTE9WRU1ZU0VMRklFIChGRUFUVVJFKQMG5wcHAgI4NAcCB1RIRUFUUkUHAgoxMyBMICBQICBWBwAHAAb//wQFAU8BAAcCDChVTilDUkVESVRFRAMG5gcHAgI0NgcCBk9OTElORQcCCTEwLTEyUEcgTAcABwAG//8EBgA9BwIDLjQ1AwbXBwcCAjkzBwISRElHSVRBTCBWSURFTyBESVNDBwIIMTggTCBTIFYHAAcABv//BAZlKQcCCytUSEUrREFNTkVEAwbVBwcCAjcxBwISRElHSVRBTCBWSURFTyBESVNDBwIEUEcgTAcABwAG//8EBuoKBwIMMSBHSUFOVCBMRUFQAwbSBwcCAzEyOQcCEkRJR0lUQUwgVklERU8gRElTQwcCBDE2IEwHAAcABv//BAaOGwcCDDEgR0lBTlQgTEVBUAMG0gcHAgMxMjkHAgVWSURFTwcCBDE2IEwHAAcABv//BAZaAwcCHzEgUFcgV1JFU1RMSU5HIC0gQkxPT0QgQU5EIEdVVFMDBtgHBwIDMjMwBwISRElHSVRBTCBWSURFTyBESVNDBwIDMTYgBwAHAAb//wQGEhMHAgIxMAMGzwcHAgMxMTYHAhJESUdJVEFMIFZJREVPIERJU0MHAgMxMyAHAAcABv//BAYhQAcCAjEwAwbXBwcCAzEyMgcCEkRJR0lUQUwgVklERU8gRElTQwcCAzEzIAcABwAG//8EBlRRBwIaMTAgQUNUSU9OIE1PVklFUyAoQk9YIFNFVCkDBtUHBwIBMAcCEkRJR0lUQUwgVklERU8gRElTQwcCBjE2IEwgVgcABwAG//8EBa4xAQAHAhMxMCBDTE9WRVJGSUVMRCBMQU5FAwbgBwcCAjk5BwISRElHSVRBTCBWSURFTyBESVNDBwIJMTAtMTJQRyBWBwAHAAb//wQFWC0BAAcCEzEwIENMT1ZFUkZJRUxEIExBTkUDBt8HBwIDMTA0BwIIVEhFQVRSRSAHAgQxMyBWBwAHAAb//wQFVCwBAAcCHzEwIENMT1ZFUkZJRUxEIExBTkUgKFRSQUlMRVIgQSkDBt8HBwIBMwcCCFRIRUFUUkUgBwIIMTAtMTJQRyAHAAcABv//BAXnNgEABwITMTAgREFZUyBJTiBTVU4gQ0lUWQMG4QcHAgI4NwcCCFRIRUFUUkUgBwIHMTMgTCAgVgcABwAG//8EBek2AQAHAhkxMCBEQVlTIElOIFNVTiBDSVRZIFRSTCAxAwbhBwcCATIHAghUSEVBVFJFIAcCCTEwLTEyUEcgVgcABwAG//8EBlhPBwIOMTAgREFZUyBUTyBXQVIDBtkHBwIDMTAyBwISRElHSVRBTCBWSURFTyBESVNDBwIEMTAgTAcABwAG//8EBhBQBwILMTAgREVBRCBNRU4DBtkHBwICOTMHAhJESUdJVEFMIFZJREVPIERJU0MHAgYxOCBMIFYHAAcABv//BAYhJQcCDTEwIEdMQURJQVRPUlMDBtYHBwIDMTAxBwISRElHSVRBTCBWSURFTyBESVNDBwIEMTAgVgcABwAG//8EBkw5BwIQMTAgSVRFTVMgT1IgTEVTUwMG1wcHAgI2NQcCEkRJR0lUQUwgVklERU8gRElTQwcCA1BHIAcABwAG//8EBphNBwIQMTAgSVRFTVMgT1IgTEVTUwMG2QcHAgI3NgcCEkRJR0lUQUwgVklERU8gRElTQwcCA1BHIAcABwAG//8EBskvBwIdMTAgS1VORyBGVSBDTEFTU0lDUyAoQk9YIFNFVCkDBtUHBwIBMAcCEkRJR0lUQUwgVklERU8gRElTQwcCBDE2IFYHAAcABv//BAUKUwEABwISMTAgTElWRVMgKEZFQVRVUkUpAwboBwcCAjg4BwIHVEhFQVRSRQcCBFBHIFYHAAcABv//BAXSUgEABwIQMTAgTElWRVMgKFRSTCBBKQMG6AcHAgEyBwIGT05MSU5FBwIEUEcgVgcABwAG//8EBoNUBwIWMTAgTUFHTklGSUNFTlQgS0lMTEVSUwMG2QcHAgI4NgcCEkRJR0lUQUwgVklERU8gRElTQwcCBjEzUEcgVgcABwAG//8EBvlpBwIWMTAgTUlOVVRFUyBUTyBNSUROSUdIVAMG3AcHAgI5OAcCEkRJR0lUQUwgVklERU8gRElTQwcCCjE4IEwgTiBTIFYHAAcABv//BAbKLwcCKDEwIE1PVklFUyAtIEhPTExZV09PRCBCQUQgQk9ZUyAoQk9YIFNFVCkDBtUHBwIBMAcCEkRJR0lUQUwgVklERU8gRElTQwcCCjE2IEwgTiBTIFYHAAcABv//BAb2LgcCJTEwIE1PVklFUyAtIEhPTExZV09PRCBESVZBUyAoQk9YIFNFVCkDBtUHBwIBMAcCEkRJR0lUQUwgVklERU8gRElTQwcCAzE4IAcABwAG//8EBjlKBwIfMTAgUVVFU1RJT05TIEZPUiBUSEUgREFMQUkgTEFNQQMG2AcHAgI4NwcCEkRJR0lUQUwgVklERU8gRElTQwcCA1BHIAcABwAG//8EBkNDBwITMTAgUklMTElOR1RPTiBQTEFDRQMG1wcHAgMxMDYHAhJESUdJVEFMIFZJREVPIERJU0MHAgQxMCBWBwAHAAb//wQGthoHAhoxMCBUSElOR1MgSSBIQVRFIEFCT1VUIFlPVQMGzwcHAgI5NAcCEkRJR0lUQUwgVklERU8gRElTQwcCAzEwIAcABwAG//8EBrcaBwIaMTAgVEhJTkdTIEkgSEFURSBBQk9VVCBZT1UDBs8HBwICOTQHAgVWSURFTwcCAzE2IAcABwAG//8EBf7/AAAHAhoxMCBUSElOR1MgSSBIQVRFIEFCT1VUIFlPVQMGzwcHAgI5NQcCB1RIRUFUUkUHAgNQRyAHAAcABv//BAX1PQEABwIHMTAgWCAxMAMG4gcHAgI4MwcCEkRJR0lUQUwgVklERU8gRElTQwcCBzE2IEwgIFYHAAcABv//BAVpBwEABwIJMTAsMDAwIEJDAwbYBwcCAzEwOAcCB1RIRUFUUkUHAgQxMyBWBwAHAAb//wQGJlkHAgkxMCwwMDAgQkMDBtoHBwIDMTA0BwIMQkxVLVJBWSBESVNDBwIEMTMgVgcABwAG//8EBlZFBwIJMTAsMDAwIEJDAwbYBwcCAzEwNAcCEkRJR0lUQUwgVklERU8gRElTQwcCBDEzIFYHAAcABv//BAaqXAcCCDEwMCBEQVlTAwbaBwcCAzEzMwcCEkRJR0lUQUwgVklERU8gRElTQwcCBjEzUEcgVgcABwAG//8EBiBfBwIWMTAwIERBWVMgSU4gVEhFIEpVTkdMRQMG2gcHAgI5MwcCEkRJR0lUQUwgVklERU8gRElTQwcCBjEzIEwgVgcABwAG//8EBplfBwIIMTAwIEZFRVQDBtsHBwICOTIHAhJESUdJVEFMIFZJREVPIERJU0MHAggxNiBMIFMgVgcABwAG//8EBqASBwIJMTAwIEdJUkxTAwbSBwcCAjkyBwIFVklERU8HAgQxNiBTBwAHAAb//wQGoRIHAgkxMDAgR0lSTFMDBtIHBwICOTIHAhJESUdJVEFMIFZJREVPIERJU0MHAgQxNiBTBwAHAAb//wQGmA8HAg0xMDAgTUlMRSBSVUxFAwbTBwcCAjk4BwISRElHSVRBTCBWSURFTyBESVNDBwIEMTYgTAcABwAG//8EBj0gBwINMTAwIE1JTEUgUlVMRQMG0wcHAgI5OAcCBVZJREVPBwIEMTYgTAcABwAG//8EBtRdBwIOMTAwIE1JTExJT04gQkMDBtoHBwICODUHAhJESUdJVEFMIFZJREVPIERJU0MHAgYxNiBMIFYHAAcABv//BAXcMwEABwILMTAwIFNUUkVFVFMDBuEHBwICODkHAhJESUdJVEFMIFZJREVPIERJU0MHAgoxNiBEICBMICBWBwAHAAb//wQGcgkHAhoxMDAgV09NRU4gKEFLQSBHSVJMIEZFVkVSKQMG0gcHAgI5MQcCEkRJR0lUQUwgVklERU8gRElTQwcCBDEzIFMHAAcABv//BAZzCQcCGjEwMCBXT01FTiAoQUtBIEdJUkwgRkVWRVIpAwbSBwcCAjkxBwIFVklERU8HAgQxMyBTBwAHAAb//wQGfmsHAhExMDAlIFZPTFJPT00gTUVMVAMG3QcHAgI1NAcCEkRJR0lUQUwgVklERU8gRElTQwcCBjEzIEwgRAcABwAG//8EBe5IAQAHAgkxMDAlIFdPTEYDBuQHBwICOTYHAgdUSEVBVFJFBwIGNy05UEcgBwAHAAb//wQFJkEBAAcCETEwMCwgVEhFIFNFQVNPTiA1AwbiBwcCAzUzMwcCEkRJR0lUQUwgVklERU8gRElTQwcCDTE4IEQgIEggIEwgIFYHAAcABv//BAXdUAEABwIKMTAwMSBEQVlTIAMG5wcHAgI5OAcCBk9OTElORQcCCDE2IFNWICBWBwAHAAb//wQGZWsHAg8xMDBNICAgTEVFVUxPT1ADBt0HBwICOTMHAhJESUdJVEFMIFZJREVPIERJU0MHAgNQRyAHAAcABv//BAUODAEABwINMTAwTSBMRUVVTE9PUAMG3QcHAgI5NAcCB1RIRUFUUkUHAgNQRyAHAAcABv//BAbIGgcCHjEwMSBEQUxNQVRJT05TIChFWFRSQSBGT09UQUdFKQMG0QcHAgE5BwISRElHSVRBTCBWSURFTyBESVNDBwICQSAHAAcABv//BAYRBwcCHDEwMSBEQUxNQVRJT05TIChMSVZFIEFDVElPTikDBtMHBwICOTkHAhJESUdJVEFMIFZJREVPIERJU0MHAgJBIAcABwAG//8EBYT/AAAHAg0xMDEgUkVZS0pBVklLAwbSBwcCAzEwNAcCB1RIRUFUUkUHAgQxOCBTBwAHAAb//wQFPAABAAcCDjEwMiBEQUxNQVRJT05TAwbQBwcCAzEwMAcCB1RIRUFUUkUHAgJBIAcABwAG//8EBhIHBwIdMTAyIERBTE1BVElPTlMoRVhUUkEgRk9PVEFHRSkDBtEHBwIDMTI3BwISRElHSVRBTCBWSURFTyBESVNDBwICQSAHAAcABv//BAW0PAEABwIMMTAyIE5PVCBPVVQgAwbiBwcCAzEyMAcCCFRIRUFUUkUgBwIIMTAtMTJQRyAHAAcABv//BAVQPAEABwIXMTAyIE5PVCBPVVQgLSBUUkFJTEVSIEEDBuIHBwIBMgcCCFRIRUFUUkUgBwICQSAHAAcABv//BAZqYAcCIjEwNDA6IENIUklTVElBTklUWSBJTiBUSEUgTkVXIEFTSUEDBtsHBwICNzgHAhJESUdJVEFMIFZJREVPIERJU0MHAgNQRyAHAAcABv//BAZkOQcCDTEwVEggQU5EIFdPTEYDBtcHBwIDMTA0BwISRElHSVRBTCBWSURFTyBESVNDBwIGMTYgTCBWBwAHAAb//wQG3zwHAhgxMSBEQVlTIDExIE5JR0hUUyBQQVJUIDEDBtcHBwICNjAHAhJESUdJVEFMIFZJREVPIERJU0MHAgNQRyAHAAcABv//BAbePAcCGDExIERBWVMgMTEgTklHSFRTIFBBUlQgMgMG1wcHAgI0NQcCEkRJR0lUQUwgVklERU8gRElTQwcCA1BHIAcABwAG//8EBihCBwILMTEgVEggIEhPVVIDBtgHBwICODkHAhJESUdJVEFMIFZJREVPIERJU0MHAgNQRyAHAAcABv//BAYKKAcCBTExLjE0AwbVBwcCAjgyBwIFVklERU8HAgYxNiBMIFYHAAcABv//BAYdVQcCBTExLjE0AwbVBwcCAjgyBwISRElHSVRBTCBWSURFTyBESVNDBwIGMTYgTCBWBwAHAAb//wQFTi8BAAcCETExLjIyLjYzIFNFQVNPTiAxAwbgBwcCAzQxOAcCEkRJR0lUQUwgVklERU8gRElTQwcCBzEzIEwgIFYHAAcABv//BAZLTwcCBTExOjE0AwbZBwcCAjgyBwISRElHSVRBTCBWSURFTyBESVNDBwIIMTYgTCBTIFYHAAcABv//BAaiOQcCBTExOjU5AwbXBwcCAzEwMAcCEkRJR0lUQUwgVklERU8gRElTQwcCBDEzIEwHAAcABv//BAY1ZQcCCDExLTExLTExAwbbBwcCAjkzBwISRElHSVRBTCBWSURFTyBESVNDBwIGMTMgViBCBwAHAAb//wQGPU0HAg4xMVRIICBIT1VSLFRIRQMG2AcHAgI5MgcCEkRJR0lUQUwgVklERU8gRElTQwcCA1BHIAcABwAG//8EBSwGAQAHAgkxMVRIIEhPVVIDBtcHBwICOTEHAgdUSEVBVFJFBwIDUEcgBwAHAAb//wQGhhQHAh8xMVRIIEhPVVIgIFRIRSAtIFNUT1JJRVMgRlJPTSBBAwbOBwcCATcHAhJESUdJVEFMIFZJREVPIERJU0MHAgJBIAcABwAG//8EBrcOBwIMMTIgQU5HUlkgTUVOAwbRBwcCAjkzBwISRElHSVRBTCBWSURFTyBESVNDBwIDUEcgBwAHAAb//wQGaTMHAhQxMiBET0dTIE9GIENIUklTVE1BUwMG1QcHAgMxMDMHAhJESUdJVEFMIFZJREVPIERJU0MHAgNQRyAHAAcABv//BAZGQgcCEDEyIEhPVVJTIFRPIExJVkUDBtgHBwICODkHAhJESUdJVEFMIFZJREVPIERJU0MHAgYxMCBTIFYHAAcABv//BAaHHQcCCjEyIE1PTktFWVMDBtEHBwIDMTI0BwISRElHSVRBTCBWSURFTyBESVNDBwIGMTMgTCBWBwAHAAb//wQFRicBAAcCFTEyIE1PTktFWVMgLSBTRUFTT04gMQMG3wcHAgM1MzcHAhJESUdJVEFMIFZJREVPIERJU0MHAgQxNiBWBwAHAAb//wQFIDABAAcCFTEyIE1PTktFWVMgLSBTRUFTT04gMgMG4AcHAgM1NTgHAhJESUdJVEFMIFZJREVPIERJU0MHAgcxNiBIICBWBwAHAAb//wQGJxsHAg8xMiBPJ0NMT0NLIEhJR0gDBtIHBwIDMTI4BwISRElHSVRBTCBWSURFTyBESVNDBwICQSAHAAcABv//BAbGIQcCDzEyIE8nQ0xPQ0sgSElHSAMG1AcHAgEwBwISRElHSVRBTCBWSURFTyBESVNDBwICQSAHAAcABv//BAVRCAEABwIJMTIgUk9VTkRTAwbZBwcCAzEwNwcCB1RIRUFUUkUHAgYxMyBMIFYCBVN0YXRlB2AHBgcAAgEHAQIBBwICAQcDAgEHBAIBBwUCAQcABwAHAAcAAgAFAAAAgAkCCm1hdGVyaWFsaWQHAQIKbWF0ZXJpYWxpZAQJAgACAAMHBAIABwACAQWfmwAABwACAQcABwACCFBhZ2VTaXplAwdk"
}

page = 1
digits = len(str(page - 1))

callback_param = "c0:KV|777;['82781','77392','73876','27414','86034','86724','84572','74413','86693','74712','86197','86844','74646','86076','78745','541','24883','86596','85761','15616','10597','2794','7054','858','4882','16417','20820','78254','77144','76884','79591','79593','20312','20496','9505','14668','19864','12233','86794','86738','21635','27129','12234','12022','19001','17219','6838','6839','65534','81397','67433','22822','17750','23722','24352','24473','4768','4769','3992','8253','24020','78812','2418','2419','27518','84206','82214','86237','27493','68622','6856','1809','65412','65596','1810','81076','80976','24682','14692','15583','15582','16936','10250','21789','77646','20299','14754','25909','19773','67116','5254','3767','13161','16966','7559','75590','77856','6951','8646','67665'];{args};"
args = f'GB|{digits + 19};12|PAGERONCLICK{digits + 2}|PN{page - 1}'
data["__CALLBACKPARAM"] = callback_param.format(args=args)

url = 'https://apps.fpb.org.za/erms/fpbquerytitle.aspx'
response = requests.post(url, params=params, headers=headers, data=data)
print(response.text)


You can try:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with requests.session() as s:
    ### REQUESTING FIRST PAGE
    r = s.request(
        "get",
        "https://apps.fpb.org.za/erms/fpbquerytitle.aspx?filmtitle=&Submit1=Search",
    )
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

    ### REQUESTING SECOND PAGE
    page_number = 2
    form_data = {
        "__EVENTTARGET": "",
        "__EVENTARGUMENT": "",
        "__VIEWSTATE": soup.find("input", id="__VIEWSTATE").get("value"),
        "__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR": soup.find("input", id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR").get(
            "value"
        ),
        "__EVENTVALIDATION": soup.find("input", id="__EVENTVALIDATION").get("value"),
        "vwfpbquerytitle_DXKVInput": soup.find(
            "input", id="vwfpbquerytitle_DXKVInput"
        ).get("value"),
        "vwfpbquerytitle$CallbackState": soup.find(
            "input", id="vwfpbquerytitle_CallbackState"
        ).get("value"),
        "vwfpbquerytitle$DXSelInput": soup.find(
            "input", id="vwfpbquerytitle_DXSelInput"
        ).get("value")
        or "",
        "vwfpbquerytitle_DXHFPWS": soup.find("input", id="vwfpbquerytitle_DXHFPWS").get(
            "value"
        ),
        "popupControlWS": soup.find("input", id="popupControlWS").get("value"),
        "DXScript": "1_155,1_87,1_147,1_97,1_123,1_106,1_113,1_84,1_139,1_137,1_98,1_135",
        "__CALLBACKID": "vwfpbquerytitle",
    }

    out = []
    for a in soup.select('a[href*="OnMoreInfoClick"]'):
        n = a["href"].split("'")[1]
        out.append(f"'{n}'")
    out = "[" + ",".join(out) + "]"

    form_data["vwfpbquerytitle$DXKVInput"] = out
    form_data["__CALLBACKPARAM"] = (
        "c0:KV|777;" + out + f";GB|20;12|PAGERONCLICK3|PN{page_number - 1};"
    )

    r2 = s.post(
        "https://apps.fpb.org.za/erms/fpbquerytitle.aspx?filmtitle=&Submit1=Search",
        data=form_data,
    )
    print(r2.text)

Prints:
136|/wEdAARKrjU6Djm/Pf2UMfsBdPBueGtl5Zjo7OaqmtERWdpGb1qEr2S6U0cHWeDguTOoFcLDUR1PJV1y6+qSR+KbO2bjbpAeGOCx0AJxom1Uvdz2mU2AKpI22OI5W9ESvqARKTM=/*DX*/({'id':0,'result':'<table id="vwfpbquerytitle_DXMainTable" class="dxgvTable_PlasticBlue" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" onclick="aspxGVTableClick(&#39;vwfpbquerytitle&#39;, event);" style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;empty-cells:show;">

...


This doesn't work for requesting any pages after requesting page 2. It just returns the same data that was present in page 2. The __CALLBACKPARAM does not keep the same structure i.e. 'c0:KV|777' changes to seemingly random values like 'c0:KV|771', 774, 769, etc. and 'PAGERONCLICK3' becomes 'PAGERONCLICK5' for later pages at p. ~390.

I considered writing an answer to this post, but when I came across your solution, I gave it a quick test and found it working flawlessly. Whatever page number I input into the page_number variable or use to create a range, the script parses data from that page accordingly, so your answer should be accepted @Andrej Kesely.

@SIM Have you tried to test the code with any page number containing 2 or more digits? It returns a wrong page. For example 127 or 177 will give you the same result as page 1, or 55 will give you result from page 5. I didn't test much more. But can tell that hard-coded values in this answer, which OP calls "random", are not random at all. They represent length of the string. Actual syntax is value type id | len(value) ; value ; So for 2 digit pages, it will be GB|21;12|PAGERONCLICK4|PN{page_number - 1};. For 3 digit pages GB|22;12|PAGERONCLICK5|PN{page_number - 1};

@ElisEvans I think my other comment is enough to get your project done. If you can use Selenium, much easier way to request a page is via this simple javascript call aspxGVPagerOnClick('vwfpbquerytitle','PN177');
